# Вставка и изменение строки в базе данных с помощью EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

У меня есть метод, который принимает вью-модель и вставляет новую строку или изменяет старую в таблице и возвращает Guid как на примере:

```
public async Task<Guid> SaveData(ViewModel model)
{
    bool isNew = model.Id == null;
    var dbEntity = isNew ? new DbEntity() : await DB.Table.SingleOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == model.Id);

    if (isNew)
        dbEntity.Id = new Guid();

    dbEntity.CreateDate = isNew ? new DateTime() : dbEntity.CreateDate;
    dbEntity.ModifyDate = new DateTime();
    dbEntity.value1 = model.value1;
    dbEntity.value2 = model.value2;
    dbEntity.value3 = model.value3;
    dbEntity.value4 = model.value4;
    dbEntity.value5 = model.value5;

    if (isNew)
       DB.Table.Add(dbEntity);

    await DB.SaveChangesAsync();

    return dbEntity.Id;
}
```

Можно ли как-то переписать его чтобы избежать повторяющихся похожих строк? Таких методов надо много, да и столбцов в таблицах тоже не мало, иногда присутствует некая логика по переводу из ViewModel в Entity, для каждой таблицы своя. Возможно есть какое-то архитектурное решение?

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: прошу прощения, перевел на русский

Comment: Ну если допустимо не плодить кучу одноимённых переменных, а использовать вместо них массив - то какие проблемы?

Comment: насколько я понимаю, проблема в ручном написании мапинга одной модели на другую в куче разных методов, что порождает много одинакового кода даже для одной и той же сущности? Как вариант, в одной из моделей явно прописать оператор приведения, он же каст, и потом везде использовать его. Можно определить класс посредник или мапер, который будет принимать на вход две модели и сопоставлять их когда необходимо. Можно попробовать какой-то автоматический мапер для этих целей, но тут для меня вопрос очень спорный, если есть какая-то нетривиальная логика преобразования между моделями.

Comment: По сути это и есть маппер, так как только этот метод будет использоваться для данной сущности. Согласен, что возможно стоит само приведение моделей вынести отдельно от работы с EntityFramework, но тут скорее вопрос в красоте и читабельности этого приведения моделей, используя либо возможности самого EntityFramework, либо синтаксический сахар новых версий (по типу спред-оператора в js :-), я не всё знаю в новых версиях c#), либо архитектурно